# Formatting index of a pandas table in a plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to annotate my plot with part of a dataframe. However, the time 00:00:00 is appearing in all the row labels. Is there a clean way to remove them since my data is daily in frequency? I have tried the normalize function but that doesn't remove the time; it just zeroes the time.

Here is what the issue looks like and the sample code to reproduce the issue.
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.tools.plotting import table

# Setup of mock data
date_range = pd.date_range('2014-01-01', '2015-01-01', freq='MS')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': np.random.rand(0, 10, len(date_range))}, index=date_range)

# The plotting of the table
fig7 = plt.figure()
ax10 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))
table(ax10, np.round(df.tail(5), 2), loc='center', colWidths=[0.1] * 2)
fig7.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply access the [`.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) attribute of the `DateTimeIndex` so that every individual element of your index would be represented in `datetime.date` format.

The default `DateTimeIndex` format is `datetime.datetime` which gets defined automatically even if you didn't explicitly define your index that way before.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.tools.plotting import table   

np.random.seed(42)
# Setup of mock data
date_range = pd.date_range('2014-01-01', '2015-01-01', freq='MS')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': np.random.rand(len(date_range))}, date_range)
df.index = df.index.date                                   # <------  only change here

# The plotting of the table
fig7 = plt.figure()
ax10 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))
table(ax10, np.round(df.tail(5), 2), loc='center', colWidths=[0.1] * 2)
fig7.show()
```

[image]